# Python Mongoalchemy Ref field at same class

Tags: python, mongoalchemy

Im stuck trying to solve this:

```
class User(db.Document):
    date_add = db.CreatedField()
    date_update = db.ModifiedField()
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    active = db.BoolField()
    admin = db.BoolField()
    user_add = db.IntField()
    user_update = db.IntField()

    user_add = db.SRefField(type = User, default = None)
    ser_update = db.SRefField(type = User, default = None)
```

console says: `NameError: name 'User' is not defined`, there is some way to handle this?

**UPDATE**

i ve found the same problem while using the DocumentField class, defining a field like `myfield= db.DocumentField(Myclass)`inside `Myclass` create the same error above and cant still figure it out

Comment: Try passing a string in the *self reference*: `user_add = db.SRefField(type='User', default=None)`

Comment: wow, i think ve tried everythink except this. Thanks!